# Combinatorics and statistics question regarding drawing every element

Tags: combinatorics, statistics, coupon-collector

Assuming a set of size X, on average how many attempts would it take to randomly draw every element in the set (returning it back after drawing)?

*I have a hard time formulating a title for this question so if anyone can do it after reading my question I would be thankful.*

Comment: This is the *coupon collector's problem*: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem

Comment: Thanks Lord Shark, that helped a lot!